# Zero validation Regular Expression

Tags: regex, validation

I have a small test to match using regex.

Match to true if and only if user has entered "0000" or 000 or 00 or 0.

0001 or 0011, 1000, 0111, 1111 should return false.

Here is what i have tried : `/^0*([0]{1,4})/` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
/^0{1,4}$/
```